# Bottom DockPanel for Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I want to have a `DockPanel` (with opacity) at the bottom of `Image` control: `DockPanel` width should be equal to current `Image` width.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="..." />

    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" LastChildFill="True" Opacity="0.5">
      <Button Content="Play" />
      <ProgressBar Value="50" Maximum="100" Height="40" />
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

With this XAML: the width of the `DockPanel` is not equal to the `Image` width. The `DockPanel` width is set to `Window` width.

Comment: I'm missing the `Grid.Row="0"` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need  (with binding)

```
<Image Source="..." Name=myImg/> 


<DockPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=myImg, Path=ActualWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" LastChildFill="True" Opacity="0.5" >
```

A possible solution without binding is

```
<Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source=... /> 

            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" LastChildFill="True" Opacity="0.5" > 
              <Button Content="Play" /> 
              <ProgressBar Value="50" Maximum="100" Height="40" /> 
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. But is there some more elegant solution? Maybe some layout control (grid, panel, etc) to solve this task?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the solution with `Viewbox`. Button text size and frame line widths are scaled within `Viewbox`. How to fix that?

Comment: I see, this suggests me that the solution with databinding is the one to use.